# Call Blackbaud Raiser's Edge VBA code from outside API Application

Tags: vb.net

This might be a bit of a specialized question but I hope somebody can give me some guidance here.

**Environment**

I am using a non-profit CRM system from Blackbaud called the Raiser's Edge. One can customize it with a built-in VBA module as well as plugins and standalone applications that access its extensive API. In the VBA one can customize also events that fire when records get opened, saved etc.

**What I am trying to do**

I am developing an vb.net application using Raiser's Edge's API. I need to call code that is stored in the VBA module. This specific code usually only gets called when a record is open in the main application is open and you save it.

I am also able to call this code using the following line:

`Dim sc as IBBSessionContext`

`sc = REAPI.SessionContext`

`sc.VBAObject.Host.Projects.Item(1).Run("RE_System_Object_Code", "Constituent_BeforeSave", oRec, False)`

**Problem**

The problem is that the `VBAObject = Nothing` during runtime and creates an exception when.

I have no idea how to initialize this object so I can use it.

I have checked [Blackbaud's Website](http://blackbaud.com), their help file and guides and have not found a reference on how to do this. Unfortunately the API documentation is lacking in some parts. I have filed a case with support but maybe somebody here is faster.

Comment: If that's an object provided by their underlying framework, it would seem to me that VBAObject should be populated within the framework. If you open up the ObjectBrowser in the VB IDE, and search for IBBSessionContext objects, you might be able to determine exactly the type of reference VBAObject is supposed to hold; you might be able to set it programmatically as a result. Just a thought.

Comment: @DavidW - Thank you. Yes, you are right. The VBAObject is a member of the IBBSessionContext object: `Property VBAObject As Blackbaud.PIA.RE7.BBREAPI.IBBVBAObject Member of Blackbaud.PIA.RE7BBREAPI.IBBSessionContext` Unfortunately I am not quite sure what to do with this. But I will run some tests.